# BeautifulSoup not finding table rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the info from [CBSsports.com golf tournament results](http://www.cbssports.com/golf/leaderboard/pga-tour/1186083/houston-open) but using beautiful soup returns only one of four table rows `<tr>` from the first of two `<tbody>` children of the `<table>`.

Inspecting in google chrome returns:
[Screenshot of chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEKna.png)

While beautiful soup returns:

```
  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="data" defaultsort="currentpos" enablesort="true" id="Leaderboard" onsort="Leaderboard.sort" width="620">
         <tr class="label" recordid="{id}"></tr>
  </table>
```

I've tried both the `html` and the `lxml parsers` to make the soup and tried both `requests.get` and `urllib.requests` to open the connection to the site but all result in the same. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The final desired output, I would like to be able to pull most of the data from the table and put into a pandas dataframe but I should be able to figure that out once i can access each of the table data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you scrape, `div#Leaderboard` doesn't contain any rows until javascript running in your browser renders them. Neither standalone [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) nor [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) does that for you. I recommend you this package [requests-html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) created by the author of very popular [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://www.cbssports.com/golf/leaderboard/pga-tour/1186083/houston-open')
r.html.render()
table = r.html.find('#Leaderboard', first=True)
```

Now the table contains rows, we can get them with the code below:

```
rows = table.find("tr[id^='Leaderboard']")
```

As you can see we successfully found the rows:

```
>>> len(rows)
144
```

There were several rows that you are probably not interested in such as: title, highlight, label and adRow. That's why I used `tr[id^='Leaderboard']` selector to filter them. It targets all `tr` with ids that starts with `Leaderboard` (e.g. id of the first row containing data is `Leaderboard401338`). You can read more about [substring matching attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) or about CSS selectors in general [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Comment: Worked Brilliantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you view source of the page then you will find that table with `id="Leaderboard"` does not contain actual rows with player data but are rendered using javascript.
`requests.get` or `urllib.request` is used to perform HTTP Requests so javascript rendering is not performed by these (your browser does that for you).
To fetch the data you have to use some framework which renders data.You can checkout [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
Using scrapy with splash is also an option.